# Accessing specific elements in a list of tuples in f# without libraries

Tags: list, recursion, f#, tuples

I have a list of tuples with three different elements like so:

`[(a0:string, b0:string, c0:int); (a1, b1, c1); (and so on...)]`.

I need to make a function that takes this list and a "name" in the form of `a` and gives a list of all the `b`s where the name matches the a in the tuple. But I'm not sure how to iterate and match everything.

```
input: function name tuplelist
output: [b0 if a0 = name; b1 if a1 = name; b2 if a2 = name]
```

**I also cannot use libraries!!!**

Comment: This task requires you to write your own recursive list processing function. Have you seen any such function at all in your class or reading material?

Comment: Yes I know how recursion works. I'm just not sure how to set it up when it comes to specific elements in a tuple :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing code in a functional style you will often use recursion, if not explicitly then implicitly since most list/array/sequence functions all use recursion under the hood.

In F#, you need to explicitly state that a function is recursive, so the function you create will use the `let rec` syntax in its definition. Given your requirements, your function will probably look like this:

```
let rec myFilter (name: string) (input: (string * string * int) list) =
    ...
```

For this class of problems, where you iterate over a list recursively, you usually use pattern matching to check if you are at the end of a list, and if so, return an empty list.

```
let rec myFilter (name: string) (input: (string * string * int) list) =
        match input with
        | [] -> []
        ...
```

Now you need to write a pattern match that checks the first item in the tuple against the supplied name. You can use pattern matching on the head of the list, and F#'s `when` syntax to deconstruct the head of the list for comparison

```
let rec myFilter (name: string) (input: (string * string * int) list) =
        match input with
        | [] -> []
        | ((a, b, _) :: rest) when a = name -> b :: myFilter name rest
        ...
```

This second case matches when `a` matches the queried name. When it matches, it will return a new list of which `b` is the head of the list, and then it will take the rest of the list of tuples and call `myFilter` recursively. This is how you iterate through the list recursively.

We have one more case to check for: If we don't find a match, we want to keep stepping through the list without collecting `b`. This can be expressed by peeling off the head and recursively calling `myFilter`, sending only the rest of the tuples.

```
let rec myFilter (name: string) (input: (string * string * int) list) =
        match input with
        | [] -> []
        | ((a, b, _) :: rest) when a = name -> b :: myFilter name rest
        | (_ :: rest) -> myFilter name rest
```

Calling `myFilter "a" [("a","x",3);("b","y",4);("a","z",5)]` then yields `["x"; "z"]`, as expected.

Comment: Thank you! Especially for explaining it step by step!

Answer (score 1):

Powerful F# pattern matching and recursion along with type inference easily compensate for dropping libraries limitation.

You need to build a `map` function converting one list into another list, this is to be addressed with recursion, the mapping function applied to each element of the list may use pattern matching to disassemble tuple into components and perform the conversion.

Something like the following will do:

```
let filter name (tupleList:(string*string*int) list) =
    let checkElement name = function | (a,b,c) -> if a = name then Some b else None
    let rec mapList name inputList outputList =
        match inputList with
        | [] -> outputList
        | h::t -> let filter = checkElement name h
                  mapList name t (if filter = None then outputList else (outputList @ [filter.Value]))
    mapList name tupleList []
```

Here `checkElement` is the mapping function that takes the `name` and a tuple (a,b,c) and returns an option value either `Some b` if a = name, or None if not.

Recursive function `mapList` on each step operates with the unprocessed part of `inputList` of tuples and `outputList` accumulating on each recursion step parts from matched elements only. On each recursion step it checks if the `inputList` is empty. If yes, then we are done and it's time to return the accumulated result, otherwise we split the head element off `inputList` and apply the mapping function to it, changing the accumulated list, if this is the case. Then we do the next recursion step on the tail of `inputList` and the accumulator.

Answer (score 0):

This task requires you to write your own recursive list processing function. I was able to implement it by using two sub-functions.

While the answers by @GeneBelitski and @ChadGilbert are great for learning, they are not tail-recursive, so I'll add my own.

Sub-function `aux` takes an accumulator and the list to process, and matches against the shape of the list. If it is empty, it returns the result accumulated so far. If it is a 3-tuple with a tail, it compares the first element to `name`, and if they are equal, continues running itself prepending the second element to the results accumulated, and the tail of the original list, otherwise just the results accumulated so far, and the tail of the original list.

As this way of accumulating results inverts the order of the resulting list, we need to reverse it before returning it; this is what the sub-function `rev` does, and as you see, the code looks almost identical to `aux`, prepending elements to the results accumulated so far but without doing any comparing or processing.

```
let filter_b name lst =
    let rec aux acc = function
        | [] -> acc
        | (a : string, b : string, c : int) :: tl ->
            if a = name
            then aux (b :: acc) tl
            else aux acc tl
    let rec rev acc = function
        | [] -> acc
        | hd :: tl -> rev (hd :: acc) tl
    lst
    |> aux []   // process list with aux function
    |> rev []   // reverse resulting list
```